# alignment look and feel of elements differs between bootstrap 3.4.1 and 4.0.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

the same html page once with included libs for bootstrap 3.4.1 differs in look and feel if bootstrap 4.0.0 is included.

here are two minimum reproduceable examples of it.

This example is working as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/203228f164.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        html {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
            background-color: grey;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        body {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainViewArea">
        <div class="navHeader">
            <nav class="navbar  navbar-inverse"
                style="border-bottom-color:#bfbfbf; border-bottom-style:solid; border-width:2px;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li style="padding-left:10px;"><a><span class="fa fa-chart-line fa-2x"></span> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="padding-left:50px;"><a><span class="fa fa-database fa-2x"></span> Data</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="Footer">
            <row>
                <div class="flexBox" style="
                                            padding-top: 10px;
                                            display: flex;
                                            flex-flow: row wrap;
                                            justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="panel panel-info" style="width: 625px;">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center"
                            style="font-size: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                            This is a panel
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </row>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/sdi2001/ax1vkL6f/6/)

The other one is misaligned like the navbar elements are not in one line or the bootstrap panel in the footer is not display anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/203228f164.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        html {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
            background-color: grey;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        body {
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainViewArea">
        <div class="navHeader">
            <nav class="navbar  navbar-inverse"
                style="border-bottom-color:#bfbfbf; border-bottom-style:solid; border-width:2px;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li style="padding-left:10px;"><a><span class="fa fa-chart-line fa-2x"></span> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="padding-left:50px;"><a><span class="fa fa-database fa-2x"></span> Data</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="Footer">
            <row>
                <div class="flexBox" style="
                                            padding-top: 10px;
                                            display: flex;
                                            flex-flow: row wrap;
                                            justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="panel panel-info" style="width: 625px;">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center"
                            style="font-size: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                            This is a panel
                            <span id="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt pull-right"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </row>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/sdi2001/uj0b7eto/3/)

Comment: Yes, the 2 versions are very different. For example, there is no `panel` in BS 4. [Read the migration docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: thank you ZIM  - that solved all my issues. what a beginner mistake...